# parse XML in iphone

Tags: iphone

I use `GDataXMLNode` to parse an XML file. My problem is that when I parse

```
<TRUSTEDVINFLAG>&#x0;</TRUSTEDVINFLAG>
```

the result is

> Entity: line 102406: parser error : xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0
>         �

Here is my code:

```
+ (NSString *)dataFilePath:(BOOL)forSave {

    NSString *documentsDirectory = @"/Users/mediatun1/Desktop/XMLTest";
    NSString *documentsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IAAT.xml"];
    if (forSave || [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath]) {
        return documentsPath;
    } else {
        return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IAAT" ofType:@"xml"];
    }

}

+ (ME2Archive *)loadParty {

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath:FALSE];
    NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSError *error;


    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];
    if (doc == nil) { return nil; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the character `&#x0;` is not valid in an XML document. Therefore there is an error creating the XML document, probably related to an encoding issue. Try using UTF-8 or checking for spurious information in the source of the document.

Example, if the header of the document says

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

this is a sample code to read a file

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"xml"]; 
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 

// this is the important part, I'm reading the nsdata as UTF-8
NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: The content of your document is irrelevant because we already know that it has a wrong character that shouldn't be there at all. Posting details on how you are creating it, or where the document comes from may be of help. eg: do you read it using NSURLConnection?, is it a file from the disk?, what code are you using?

Comment: i bilive that i can use fonction in objective to resolve the problem

Comment: i seee your solution but its difficult to used in my program

Comment: i use  - (id)initWithXMLString:(NSString *)str options:(unsigned int)mask error:(NSError **)error {

  NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  GDataXMLDocument *doc = [self initWithData:data options:mask error:error];
  return doc;
}

Comment: that looks fine, check where that str param is coming from

Answer (score 0):

You can instead, use NSXMLParser or TBXML. Can you pre-format the value of the tag? Or you are obligated to use what you receive?

Comment: In that case, assuming that GDataXMLNode is unable to process that value, I would try a different parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the line in the xml like:

```
<TRUSTEDVINFLAG><![CDATA[&#x0;]]></TRUSTEDVINFLAG>
```